# Proof of $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ incomplete

Tags: functions, inverse-function

$$f(x)=y \tag 1$$
Swapping $x$ and $y$ creating an inverse function,
$$f^{-1}(y)=x \tag 2$$
Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$,
$$f(f^{-1}(y))=y$$
But I want $x$ instead of $y$. Is it so that I can just replace $y$ with $x$ just like that, or What did I mistake?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What do you mean by $f$? Is it a general map? If so, you can't always say that $f^{-1}$ exists. If $f^{-1}$ exists, what is the (co)domain of your function? Because $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't make sense if $x$ is not in your range.

Comment: @Crostul I swapped them to create an inverse function. So I can swap $x$ and $y$ just like that w/o any special proof for $x$ instead of $y$?

Comment: @BrazilianCérebro I dont have any given data for the function. So let me assume sin for the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mistake, your result is correct. Your first equation $f(x)=y$ indicates that $x$ must lie in the domain of $f$, and $y$ in the range of $f$. What your final equation tells you is that $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for numbers $y$ which are in the range of $f$.

If your range and your domain are the same, you can simply rename your variables to get $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$.

Comment: Ooh, now I have understood! Good point, +1.

Comment: Will range and domain of $\sin$ value be the same?

Comment: No, the range of $\sin$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$, while its domain is $[-1,1]$. That is why $\arcsin$ is only defined in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Then how does [this](https://youtu.be/50i9-lVoIWs?t=4m36s) video assume so if not all functions' domain and range are the same?

Comment: There is no general rule that says "x is always in the domain, y is always in the range" - you are making that statement in your first equation. The person in the video is not cleanly distinguishing between numbers in the domain and numbers in the range of his functions, and he fails (of course) to find the inverse of $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$, he only finds it for $x>0$, i.e. for numbers in the range of $f$.

Comment: No just pause the video at 4:36. They assumed it without any proof, without knowing anything about range and domain

Comment: They write $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ which is not true in general. I will not criticise them for not adding a whole list of assumptions in what is just an introductory explanation. That formula only holds for $x$ in the domain of $f$, and only if $f$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this to me... I don't think this should be assumed as it leaves us wondering... btw swapping $y$ with $x$ means it should be in the domain of y isn't it? Like for eg,$y$ can take values from 90 to -90. $x$ can take values from 1 to -1. In this case it shall be swapped right? Or $x$ should have the range same as $y$ to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you say $g(y)=y$, you might tacitly mean that for **all** values of $y$ this equality holds, so you're saying $g(3)=3$ and $g(52)=52$ and $g(-7)=-7$ and so on.  And that's the same as saying that for **all** values of $x$ you have $g(x)=x$.  The variables $y$ and $x$ when used in this way are **bound** variables and so may be freely renamed.  Google the terms "free variable" and "bound variable".

Comment: But x should be in the range of y for swapping isnt it? For eg, if y can take values greater than 1, x can't be substituted if it takes values less than 1.

Comment: Yes.  It may be a good idea to use the letter $x$ only for things in the domain of $f$ and $y$ only for things in the codomain.  In that case, your wanting $x$ rather than $y$ in $f(f^{-1}(y) = y$ might not be a good idea.  Might it be that you wanted $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$, with $f^{-1}$ on the outside and $f$ on the inside? $\qquad$